# when submitting first apk to android platform

Tags: android, netbeans, apk

I am trying to publish my first app.
 The name of my apk is:
 AndroidApplication1-release.apk

I can't upload this apk... maybe due to its name or due to my keystore
 that I created with netbeans 7.3.1

The system doesn't like the name and says that the validity is very
 small...but I place 20 years...

Can you help me?

Also the android platform also gives a key to place in my binary...but
 how and where?

--
 Rui
http://talesforlove.blogs.sapo.pt

Comment: [From the docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html): A validity period of 25 years or more is recommended. When your key's validity period expires, users will no longer be able to seamlessly upgrade to new versions of your application.

Comment: Google won't accept a key validity with less than 50 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the guidelines at [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) website says

> In preparation for signing your application, you must first ensure that you have a suitable private key with which to sign. A suitable private key is one that:
>
> Is in your possession
> Represents the personal, corporate, or organizational entity to be identified with the application
> Has a validity period that exceeds the expected lifespan of the application or application suite. A validity period of more than 25 years is recommended.
> If you plan to publish your application(s) on Google Play, **note that a validity period ending after 22 October 2033 is a requirement.** You can not upload an application if it is signed with a key whose validity expires before that date.
> Is not the debug key generated by the Android SDK tools.